# Как удалить необходимый блок тегов регуляркой на php?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Существует такой код:

```
<div>
text0
<div id="adblock_1" >
<div class="warning_block">
<div id="adblock_detected_message">
<div>Text1</div>
<div>Text2</div>
</div>
<div id="adblock_close_button">
<img src="close_button.png" alt="close button" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
text4
</div>
```

Нужно удалить всё содержимое между **text0** и **text4** 
использую следующее регулярное выражение:

```
$buffer=preg_replace("/<div id=\"adblock_1\"(.*?)<\/div>/is","", $buffer, -1, $count);
```

Проблема в том, что удаляется всё до первого закрытого тега `</div>`
, но не до последнего. Нужно, чтоб удалялось всё дерево от **text0** до **text4**. Значения **text0** и **text4** соответственно постоянно меняются, их нельзя использовать как паттерны.

Comment: domDocument вам в помощь

Comment: так если "всё содержимое между text0 и text4", то почему бы так и не вырезать? Т.е. как-то так `$buffer=preg_replace("/text0.*text4/is","", $buffer, -1, $count);` Только, по-моему, задача у вас немнго не так поставлена, надо не текст между вырезать, а полностью блок с id = adblock_1, ведь так?

Comment: @BOPOH именно так, а text0 и text4 не можем использовать как паттерны, я написал в конце описания задачи.

Comment: @valextt, просмотрел, в любом случае цель - не то, что между ними вырезать, а удалить блок #adblock_1, ведь так?

Comment: @BOPOH именно так...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если очень хочется регуляркой, то [она выглядит так](https://regex101.com/r/gZ7bY0/2)

```
preg_replace('/<div id=\"adblock_1\".*?>(<div.*?>(?1)*?<\/div>|.)*?<\/div>/is','',$str);
```

Так как у нас вложенная структура данных неизвестной глубины, то и регулярка должна быть рекурсивной. По шагам:

```
<div\ id=\"adblock_1\".*?>  # нашли начало блока
 (                          # Выделяем ВЫРАЖЕНИЕ1, для последующей ссылки
  <div.*?>                  # Оно может состоять из <div...>
     (?1)*?                 #  внутри которого может повторятся ВЫРАЖЕНИЕ1 0 и более раз
                            #  т.е. мы рекурсивно выполняем ту же часть выражения !
  <\/div>                   #  до закрывающего тега </div>
   |.                       #  ИЛИ 1 любой символ
 )*?                        # Закрывается ВЫРАЖЕНИЕ1. повторяем много раз
<\/div>                     # пока не найдем нужный нам </div>
```

Comment: ГЕНИАЛЬНО!!! Спасибо, это самый продуктивный вариант!

Comment: @valextt Я вдруг понял, что там условие излишне и ее еще упростил, вот только что :)

Comment: Супер! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

если использовать DomDocument, то так

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$ad = $xpath->query('//div[@id="adblock_1"]');
if($ad->length) 
  $ad->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($ad->item(0));

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[Демо код](https://eval.in/534595)